# Fetching Facebook Page Comments and Ratings

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook's Graph API in to fetch ratings and reviews from Facebook page. The type of my app is a Business App. Am able to pull the page likes but unable to pull reviews and ratings.
As per my understanding the facebook reviews can be given when giving rating to a page and the API endpoint for getting ratings is

`{page_id}/ratings`

But I get this when I hit the endpoint

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#283) Requires pages_read_user_content permission to manage the object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 283,
    "fbtrace_id": "ArxjZMuaMR6yXBEOBisJI8i"
  }
}
```

As I understand I need to verify my business with Facebook in order to get access to this endpoint.
But my question is Am I hitting the right API?

Or is there another endpoint which fetches the reviews. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your access token. I think the permission is missing there. As a developer you can use the permission without review, but your customers can't.

Comment: "But my question is Am I hitting the right API?" Do it with the app in development mode and as one of the administrators of the app and it should bypass the permissions check so you can find out.

Comment: @Norbert Am currently using the Graph API Explorer to make requests which does not need me to input the access token. I only need to select Page Access Tokens from the dropdown "User or Page". Still it gives me the error message. Also for Business apps it says there is no developer mode.

Comment: @ceejayoz The business app has no option for a Development Mode. I checked and it said business apps have permissions but the basic permissions seem to be given already.
As for the administrator, I am currently the administrator of my app. Still getting above error.

Comment: Just grant the mentioned permission in Graph API Explorer, and see what happens …?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I had to grant the permission and generate the page token again. It worked then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Step 1 : You have to generate an access_token for the facebook account. While doing this you need to ask for the page_read_user_content permission.

Step 2 : The access_token can be used to get all the pages related to the account.

`me/accounts`

This will return all the pages and ids associated with those pages. This will also return a Page Access Token to that page.

Step 3 : You can get the ratings and reviews for your page with this access token and page id

`{page_id}/ratings`